# C++ meta-programming: overloading of arithmetic operators for types

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, metaprogramming

Suppose the following class calculates an arithmetic composition of two functions (represented by functors Function1 and Function2):

```
template<typename Function1, typename Function2, typename BinaryOp> Compose
{
  // schematically:
  // int operator() = Function1().operator() BinaryOp Function2.operator();
};
```

With this one could write, for instance,

```
typedef Compose<F,G,Division> F_div_G;
```

to obtain a new functor implementing F/G. This could be used, for instance, like this:

```
F f;
G g;
F_div_G f_div_g;
if( f(3)/g(3) == f_div_g(3) ) std::cout<<"... it works ..."<<std::endl;
```

However, by doing several compositions in this way, the code starts to become more and more unreadable.

Thus, is it possible to somehow "overload" the operator `/` (and similarly other arithmetic operators) to be able to replace `Compose<F,G,Division>` by `F/G`? Do you know a macro or something similar which safely implements this? Or, provided that it is possible, would you discourage from doing this?

Comment: What you're looking for is usually referred to as "Expression Template".

Comment: Did you have a look at boost mpl and the expression templates surrounding it as an inspiration? Other than this, I guess one could write books that would not fully answer your question...

Comment: Thanks, but I think you got me wrong a bit ... anyway your comments help to clarify my question. I know that you can use these "expression templates" to return composed objects, and I already did this in my code (actually without being aware that this is an expression template). My question was rather, whether there is such a thing which works on types, i.e., returns `decltype(f/g)` by writing `F/G` ... such that I can write `F/G f_div_g;` in the above code (...`auto f_div_g=f/g;` already works). At this point, however, I'm not sure whether it is really needed...

Comment: Operators operate on values, not types.

Comment: This is why I considered a macro.

Comment: @Xeo but values can contain no state but their type, and then be operated on!

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename F>
struct Op {
  // this is optional:
  template<typename... Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&...args)const{
    return F{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
// `Op<Compose>` lets you chain these things:
template<typename LHS, typename RHS, typename Operation>
struct Compose:Op<Compose> {
  template<typename... Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&...args)const{
    // with lots of care, perfect forwarding could be shoe horned in here, but it gets tricky:
    return Operation{}(LHS{}(args...),RHS{}(args...));
  }
};
// write one of these for each operator you want to handle:
struct Divide {
  template<typename LHS, typename RHS>
  auto operator()(LHS&& lhs,RHS&&rhs)const{
    return std::forward<LHS>(lhs)()/std::forward<RHS>(rhs);
  }
};
// write one of these as well for each operator you want to handle:
template<typename LHS,typename RHS>
Compose<LHS,RHS,Divide> operator/( Op<LHS> lhs, Op<RHS> rhs ) {
  return {};
}
```

and bob is your uncle.

```
int main() {
  auto f_div_g = Op<F>{}/Op<G>{};
  auto f_div_g_div_h = Op<F>{}/Op<G>{}/Op<H>{};
}
```

and if you want a type:

```
decltype( Op<F>{}/Op<G>{} )
```

with maybe a `std::decay` thrown in.

Comment: I would also consider `Compose<LHS, Divide, RHS>` as that might make decoding error messages easier, as most people read infix better than postfix.  And a means to make `f_div_g` take two arguments might be wise (as feeding everything the same argument seems like a strange design goal, but it was in the OP)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and +1 for the effort, however, it doesn't really answer my question (... I am as far as you presented ... although it took much more time ;-) ). Again, I was asking for a static type creator of the type `decltype(Op<F>{}/Op<G>{})` by writing, e.g., `Op<F>/Op<G>`. Thanks also for the forwarding approach, which in reality, unfortunately, is a bit trickier since the functions may have different numbers of arguments. For the even more tricky solution, see [here](http://cpptruths.blogspot.de/2012/06/perfect-forwarding-of-parameter-groups.html).

Comment: However, during the last hours, I somewhat became convinced that the goal of my question is not of all too great practical use, since you can easily use `decltype`. Still it might be interesting in principle.